Sandwhich that had prok but took out the meat and is it still Permissible to the bun only
I didn't know if this haram or halal because I had a sandwich which had meat between the buns and I took it out and I have the bread left now, is it still Permissible to eat the bread?.

Pork is najis so the bread it touched will also be najis, and thus, impermissible to eat.

Thank you very much.
